# mess with regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying the next code but it seems that i am doing something wrong.

```
import re

lista = ["\\hola\\01\\02Jan\\05\\03",
"\\hola\\01\\02Dem\\12",
"\\hola\\01\\02March\\12\\04"]

for l in lista:
    m= re.search("\\\\\d{2,2}\\\\\d{2,2}[a-zA-Z]+\\\\\d{2,2}\s",l)
    if m:
        print (m.group(0))
```

The result should be second string.
I have tried without `\s` but the result match with all strings.

Comment: Can you include expected output in question?

Comment: yes. i have edited the code because there was an errata.

Comment: If you just need to get four sequences, you can do this: ^(?:\\\\[^\\]+){4}$.  But if you care about what text those sequences contain, you will need to elaborate.

Comment: **Tip:** use `r`-strings to avoid escaping many backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
lista = [r"\hola\01\02Jan\05\03", r"\hola\01\02Dem\12", r"\hola\01\02March\12\04"]

>>> for l in lista:
...     m = re.search(r"\\\d{2,2}\\\d{2,2}[a-zA-Z]+\\\d{2}$", l)
...     if m:
...             print m.group()
...
```

**Output:**

```
\01\02Dem\12
```

- Use `r"..."` form to declare a regex and input as raw string
- Use anchor `$` to avoid matching unwanted input

Comment: thanks. with `r` i had to use only two backslash (`\\`) in regex. please correct the code if it possible. thanks once again i have learned new thing about regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code without regex:

```
>>> for l in lista:
        totalNo = l.count('\\')
        if totalNo == 4:
            print l
```